# How to identify the number for a sequence to generate unique value across 4 data centers

Tags: java, python, logic, sequence, programming-pearls

I have three data-centers with 3 oracle databases replicating using Golden gate. Every database has trigger-sequence mechanism to generate Primary keys. We are adding one more data-center to the architecture with a DB.

Logic we are using to avoid conflicts is to increment sequence values by 4 from 3 so that no conflicts are generated when transactions are replicated using Golden gate.

For e.g.

```
DB1 - SEQUENCE_1 - START WITH 1 - INCREMENT BY 4 - Next value - 5
DB2 - SEQUENCE_1 - START WITH 2 - INCREMENT BY 4 - Next value - 6
DB3 - SEQUENCE_1 - START WITH 3 - INCREMENT BY 4 - Next value - 7
DB4 - SEQUENCE_1 - START WITH 4 - INCREMENT BY 4 - Next value - 8
```

Problem statement - After cloning DB4, I need to find out the exact number I should start my sequences with so that values generated in DB4 is unique and do not generated conflicts.

Actual Values in DB for a sequence.

```
DB1 - SEQUENCE_1 - START WITH 33479805 - INCREMENT BY 4 - Next value - 33479809
DB2 - SEQUENCE_1 - START WITH 33318420 - INCREMENT BY 4 - Next value - 33318424
DB3 - SEQUENCE_1 - START WITH 47020627 - INCREMENT BY 4 - Next value - 47020631
DB4 - SEQUENCE_1 - START WITH ???????? - INCREMENT BY 4 - Next value - ???
```

If someone can help with logic which can be used for all sequences will be very helpful.

Regards,
LANCERIQUE.

Comment: Shouldn't [FLUSH SEQUENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWURF/ggsci_commands062.htm#GWURF260) take care of that?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Karol. We are not replicating sequences in Golden gate so nothing to flush. We are using our own logic to manage sequences, as illustrated above to avoid duplicate transactions.